# Why are these xrandr commands not working?

Tags: xrandr

I wonder what I am doing wrong.
It seems that the video card toggles it through the monitors and resolutions by itself so I want to eliminate the options and leave just the ones I use.
As you can see, it hasn't worked.

```
rt@mach:~$ xrandr --rmmode HDMI1 1280x1024
usage: xrandr [options]
  where options are:
  -display <display> or -d <display>
  -help
  -o <normal,inverted,left,right,0,1,2,3>
            or --orientation <normal,inverted,left,right,0,1,2,3>
  -q        or --query
  -s <size>/<width>x<height> or --size <size>/<width>x<height>
  -r <rate> or --rate <rate> or --refresh <rate>
  -v        or --version
  -x        (reflect in x)
  -y        (reflect in y)
  --screen <screen>
  --verbose
  --current
  --dryrun
  --nograb
  --prop or --properties
  --fb <width>x<height>
  --fbmm <width>x<height>
  --dpi <dpi>/<output>
  --output <output>
  --auto
  --mode <mode>
  --preferred
  --pos <x>x<y>
  --rate <rate> or --refresh <rate>
  --reflect normal,x,y,xy
  --rotate normal,inverted,left,right
  --left-of <output>
  --right-of <output>
  --above <output>
  --below <output>
  --same-as <output>
  --set <property> <value>
  --scale <x>x<y>
  --transform <a>,<b>,<c>,<d>,<e>,<f>,<g>,<h>,<i>
  --off
  --crtc <crtc>
  --panning <w>x<h>[+<x>+<y>[/<track:w>x<h>+<x>+<y>[/<border:l>/<t>/<r>/<b>]]]
  --gamma <r>:<g>:<b>
  --primary
  --noprimary
  --newmode <name> <clock MHz>
        <hdisp> <hsync-start> <hsync-end> <htotal>
        <vdisp> <vsync-start> <vsync-end> <vtotal>
        [+HSync] [-HSync] [+VSync] [-VSync]
  --rmmode <name>
  --addmode <output> <name>
  --delmode <output> <name>
```

.

```
rt@mach:~$ xrandr --delmode HDMI1 1280x1024
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  150 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (RRDeleteOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

.

```
root@mach:/home/rt# xrandr --delmode HDMI1 1280x1024
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  150 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (RRDeleteOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

.

```
root@mach:/home/rt# xrandr --rmmode HDMI1 1280x1024
usage: xrandr [options]
  where options are:
  -display <display> or -d <display>
  -help
  -o <normal,inverted,left,right,0,1,2,3>
            or --orientation <normal,inverted,left,right,0,1,2,3>
  -q        or --query
  -s <size>/<width>x<height> or --size <size>/<width>x<height>
  -r <rate> or --rate <rate> or --refresh <rate>
  -v        or --version
  -x        (reflect in x)
  -y        (reflect in y)
  --screen <screen>
  --verbose
  --current
  --dryrun
  --nograb
  --prop or --properties
  --fb <width>x<height>
  --fbmm <width>x<height>
  --dpi <dpi>/<output>
  --output <output>
  --auto
  --mode <mode>
  --preferred
  --pos <x>x<y>
  --rate <rate> or --refresh <rate>
  --reflect normal,x,y,xy
  --rotate normal,inverted,left,right
  --left-of <output>
  --right-of <output>
  --above <output>
  --below <output>
  --same-as <output>
  --set <property> <value>
  --scale <x>x<y>
  --transform <a>,<b>,<c>,<d>,<e>,<f>,<g>,<h>,<i>
  --off
  --crtc <crtc>
  --panning <w>x<h>[+<x>+<y>[/<track:w>x<h>+<x>+<y>[/<border:l>/<t>/<r>/<b>]]]
  --gamma <r>:<g>:<b>
  --primary
  --noprimary
  --newmode <name> <clock MHz>
        <hdisp> <hsync-start> <hsync-end> <htotal>
        <vdisp> <vsync-start> <vsync-end> <vtotal>
        [+HSync] [-HSync] [+VSync] [-VSync]
  --rmmode <name>
  --addmode <output> <name>
  --delmode <output> <name>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're experiencing here is this bug that was filed against Ubuntu. Titled: [xrandr error with delmode - Ubuntu “x11-xserver-utils” package Bugs Bug #364091](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/x11-xserver-utils/+bug/364091).

This problem appears to have been fixed in later versions.

*excerpt*

```
POJAR GEO (geoubuntu) wrote on 2011-06-29:
     #27 This problem is solved with latest ubuntu 11.04.
```

Comment: Using Ubuntu 18.04 this bug seems to have resurfaced. User added modes are, for some reason, marked as private (system seems to think they are being managed by x-server), thus users can add custom modes with `xrandr --addmode` but cannot delete them